# My mac bookpro screen hangs and freeze after restarting it displays black screen

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I bought macbook pro-13 inches last year September, since last 15 days I'm facing difficulties regarding to booting issues and also some times suddenly the display hangs no controls, keys, trackpad not working the display just hanged.

After restarting the device by long pressing power button and power on it after some time some times it shows some black lines appearing on screen after 30 seconds they disappear and turn into black screen sounding 3 beeps.

Last week I've consulted authorized dealer for service they just formatted my system and told me there is no problem regarding to hard-disk drive, RAM and logic board. But I'm facing this problem daily...Please tell the exact reason, and what should i do to it work properly.

Comment: Does it work in Safe mode ?

Comment: I does n't understood whats you are asking Buscar

Comment: Start your computer in Safe mode to see if it works that way. Start up--- Immediately after you hear the startup tone, hold down the Shift key.
You should press the Shift key as soon as possible after you hear the startup tone, but not before.

Comment: I've tried in the safe mode it works fine and the commands were responding little bit slower like the cursor & keyboards key strokes are displaying with high delay.

Comment: it was with logic board problem, Apple replaced my logic board in the warranty period. Now it working fine with new logic board

Answer (score 1):

The 3 beep sounds indicate problem with your EFI.

EFI is located on your disk in a hidden partition and is mainly responsible for booting and other key functions.

It is possible you do have a disk error (even if the "authorized dealer") did not find anything. I would suggest you use the Disk Utility and check your disk again and while at it repair the permissions.

[Check your version](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1237).

How to repair EFI: Find your EXACT model here.

http://support.apple.com/downloads/#macnotebooks

Comment: yeah, my mac's EFI and SMC version are upto date as per that list, when i clicked disk utilities -> Repair permissions in that it shows some errors below to each error automatically repaired it shows

Comment: my macbook pro id:macbookpro9,2
core:i5
processor:2.5ghz
RAM:4gb
ROM version:MBP91.00D3.B09
SMC:2.2f44

Comment: Hello- BusCar, the above details are ok for my macbook are not?

Comment: The Disk Utility has only limited capability for disk repair. Run following in Terminal for deep repair. "fsck" read more here http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1417

Comment: it was with logic board problem, Apple replaced my logic board in the warranty period. Now it working fine with new logic board

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting in recovery mode (hold CMD-R while switching on), and making sure that the drive and its contents are OK?

Also, if the hard disk DOES have problems, you may want to consider restoring from a backup from before you started having these problems.

Comment: Yeah, every thing done at the time of service which done on last week, the authorized service people restored the hard disk and re-installed the OSX, but it again repeating.

Comment: it was with logic board problem, Apple replaced my logic board in the warranty period. Now it working fine with new logic board.